# How can I clear all the data from my dataframes so they're empty for the next iteration through my for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've built a script that uses the Google Analytics API to grab data from multiple view IDs. At the end of the code is a for loop that runs through a number of functions I've built and builds dataframes from them. What I want to happen is that after every "loop/iteration" for each store the data is appended to a new dataframe outside the loop. I keep running into an issue though where the data appends fine for the first view ID but when it gets to the second view ID it seems to be holding on to the old data (from the first iteration) and doubling it while overwriting certain values.

For example this code....

```
lz = zip(LI, DN, VI, V, DA, S, D)
sd = '2020-08-01'
ed = '2020-08-31'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = parser.parse_args([])

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
     CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
     message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

dFI = {'DP7': 'arsseven.dat',
       'DP6': 'arssix.dat',
       'DP4': 'arsfour.dat',
       'DP0': 'arszero.dat'}

hSeg = {'DP7': {'X': 'gaid::3fifjFfj33rokQ', 'Y': 'gaid::friH58F939Fgoj3I'},
          'DP6': {'Z': 'gaid::fotkj345DdjgIcg', 'Y': 'gaid::eofWfjF5834cVfj'},
          'DP4': {'W': 'gaid::fkormvroE333nr3fg'},
          'DP0': {'V': 'gaid::Jfoeo455efFggrjor'}}

gaDO = []
gaDT = []

def getGADO(VI, sd, ed):
    l = vi_start + str(int(VI))
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(
            body={
            'reportRequests': [
            {
                'viewId': l,
                'dateRanges': [{'sd': sd, 'ed': ed}],
                'metrics': [
                    {'expression': 'ga:users'},
                    {'expression': 'ga:avgSessionDuration'}
                    ],
                'dimensions': [
                    {'name': 'ga:channelGrouping'}
                    ]
            }]}).execute()
    report_list = response.get('reports')
    for report in report_list:
        data_rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
        for row in data_rows:
            dimensions_in_row = row.get('dimensions')
            metrics_rows = row.get('metrics')
            for metrics in metrics_rows:
                metrics_values = metrics.get('values')
                full_row_data = dimensions_in_row + metrics_values
                gaDO.append(full_row_data)

    gaDON = []
    for i in gaDO:
        new_tuple = []
        new_tuple.append(i[0])
        new_tuple.append(int(i[1]))
        new_tuple.append(float(i[2]))
        gaDON.append(tuple(new_tuple))

    colO = [
    #Dimensions
    'DCG',
    #Metrics
    'Users', 'ASD']
    dfO = pd.DataFrame(gaDON, columns = colO)
    print(dfO)
    return dfO

def getGADT(VI, DA, V, sd, ed):
    l = vi_start + str(int(VI))
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(
            body={
            'reportRequests': [
            {
                'viewId': l,
                'dateRanges': [{'sd': sd, 'ed': ed}],
                'metrics': [
                    {'expression': 'ga:users'}
                    ],
                'dimensions': [
                    {'name': 'ga:channelGrouping'},
                    {'name': 'ga:segment'}
                    ],
                 'segments': [
                    {
                        'segmentId': hSeg[DA][V]
                    }]
            }]}).execute()
    report_list = response.get('reports')
    for report in report_list:
        data_rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
        for row in data_rows:
            dimensions_in_row = row.get('dimensions')
            metrics_rows = row.get('metrics')
            for metrics in metrics_rows:
                metrics_values = metrics.get('values')
                full_row_data = dimensions_in_row + metrics_values
                gaDT.append(full_row_data)

    gaDTN = []
    for i in gaDT:
        new_tuple = []
        new_tuple.append(i[0])
        new_tuple.append(int(float(i[2])))
        gaDTN.append(tuple(new_tuple))

    colT = [
    #Dimensions
    'DCG',
    #Metrics
    'TU']
    dfT = pd.DataFrame(gaDTN, columns = colT)
    print(dfT)
    return dfT

dcgX = pd.DataFrame()

for LI, DN, VI, V, DA, S, D in locations_zip:
    dID_str = str(int(LI))
    stor_str = dFI[DA]
    storage = file.Storage(stor_str)
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
    http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())
    analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)
    vi_start = 'ga:'
    dfOX = getGADO(VI, sd, ed)
    dfTX = getGADT(VI, DA, V, sd, ed)
    
    dcg = pd.merge(dfOX, dfTX, how = 'outer', on = ['DCG']).fillna(0)
    dcg = dcg[['DCG', 'Users', 'TU', 'ASD']]

    dcg.insert(loc=0, column='LI', value=LI)
    dcg.insert(loc=1, column='DN', value=DN)
    
    dcgx = dcgX.append(dcg)
```

Produces something this when it runs through the first two stores...

EDIT: Changed tables to try and show not every viewID has the same standardized set of dimension rows/values that will match from viewID to viewID. CWA for example only has Organic Search and Paid Search but not Display.

```
╔═══════╦═════╦════════════════╦═══════╦═════╦═════╗
║ DI    ║ DN  ║ DFG            ║ Users ║ TU  ║ ASD ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12345 ║ MHA ║ Organic Search ║ 4392  ║ 589 ║ 30  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12345 ║ MHA ║ Paid Search    ║ 3939  ║ 405 ║ 150 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12345 ║ MHA ║ Display        ║ 12    ║ 0   ║ 123 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Organic Search ║ 4392  ║ 589 ║ 30  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Organic Search ║ 4392  ║ 96  ║ 30  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Organic Search ║ 2489  ║ 589 ║ 121 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Organic Search ║ 2489  ║ 96  ║ 121 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Paid Search    ║ 3939  ║ 405 ║ 150 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Paid Search    ║ 3939  ║ 80  ║ 150 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Paid Search    ║ 1345  ║ 405 ║ 45  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Paid Search    ║ 1345  ║ 80  ║ 45  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Display        ║ 12    ║ 0   ║ 123 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Display        ║ 12    ║ 1   ║ 123 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Display        ║ 400   ║ 0   ║ 60  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Display        ║ 400   ║ 1   ║ 60  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 4392  ║ 589 ║ 30  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 4392  ║ 96  ║ 30  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 4392  ║ 12  ║ 30  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 2489  ║ 589 ║ 121 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 2489  ║ 96  ║ 121 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 2489  ║ 12  ║ 121 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 5888  ║ 589 ║ 75  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 5888  ║ 96  ║ 75  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 5888  ║ 12  ║ 75  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 3939  ║ 405 ║ 150 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 3939  ║ 80  ║ 150 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 3939  ║ 600 ║ 150 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 1345  ║ 405 ║ 45  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 1345  ║ 80  ║ 45  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 1345  ║ 600 ║ 45  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 7001  ║ 405 ║ 91  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 7001  ║ 80  ║ 91  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 7001  ║ 600 ║ 91  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Display        ║ 12    ║ 0   ║ 123 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Display        ║ 12    ║ 1   ║ 123 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Display        ║ 400   ║ 0   ║ 60  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Display        ║ 400   ║ 1   ║ 60  ║
╚═══════╩═════╩════════════════╩═══════╩═════╩═════╝
```

What I want it for it to look like this...

```
╔═══════╦═════╦════════════════╦═══════╦═════╦═════╗
║ DI    ║ DN  ║ DFG            ║ Users ║ TU  ║ ASD ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12345 ║ MHA ║ Organic Search ║ 4392  ║ 589 ║ 30  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12345 ║ MHA ║ Paid Search    ║ 3939  ║ 405 ║ 150 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12345 ║ MHA ║ Display        ║ 12    ║ 0   ║ 123 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Organic Search ║ 2489  ║ 96  ║ 121 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Paid Search    ║ 1345  ║ 80  ║ 45  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12346 ║ JBA ║ Display        ║ 400   ║ 1   ║ 60  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Organic Search ║ 5888  ║ 12  ║ 75  ║
╠═══════╬═════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 12347 ║ CWA ║ Paid Search    ║ 7001  ║ 600 ║ 91  ║
╚═══════╩═════╩════════════════╩═══════╩═════╩═════╝
```

I've tried clearing the dfOX and dfTX dataframes at the end of the loop (after dcgx = dcgX.append(dcg)) by using...

```
del dfOX
del dfTX
```

But that didn't work. I've also tried using .iloc[0:0] on them as well and that didn't work either.

I'm not sure how to clear the dataframe at the end of the for loop so it's empty for the next iteration. That's the only way I can think of on how to accomplish this but is there a better way?

Any insight would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `drop_duplicates` with the argument `keep` set to `last`

assuming your dataframe is called `df`

I won't speak to your code but just be aware using loops in pandas is an anti-pattern and a big no-no unless there is no other option.

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['DI','DN','DFG'],keep='last')

         DI     DN               DFG   Users     TU    ASD
1   12345.0   MHA    Organic Search   4392.0  589.0   30.0
3   12345.0   MHA    Paid Search      3939.0  405.0  150.0
5   12345.0   MHA    Display            12.0    0.0  123.0
13  12346.0   JBA    Organic Search   2489.0   96.0  121.0
21  12346.0   JBA    Paid Search      1345.0   80.0   45.0
29  12346.0   JBA    Display           400.0    1.0   60.0
```

Comment: Thank for your help! Unfortunately the data I originally provided wasn't enough to get what I'm looking for. Your answer works perfectly for what I wrote but I regrettably left out that not all of the values will be standardized. For example if I add a view ID we'll call CWA who doesn't have "Display" the df1 uses the "Display" values from JBA to fill in the missing data if that makes sense. I can always add a new table to my original question to clear this up if needed. Just let me know! Also is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do instead of using the for loop?

Comment: @AHerdofSeaCows if you change your input and output to match your requirement I'll amend my answer accordingly. There is too much code to read through and understand and I don't personally have the headspace for it. I'd read into the zen of python and the concept of keeping your code dry, clean and readable.

Comment: I updated the tables for you to see! I need help with a solution that will do what you originally showed me but works even if the data isn't standardized if that makes sense. Would it be possible somehow to have the dataframes within the loop "forget" what they wrote the previous iteration and append the new values each time to a new dataframe (dcgX) outside the loop or is that impossible?

Comment: For anyone who might need this I was able to figure out my mistake. To get the script to work properly I needed to add my function lists (gaDO = [] & gaDT = []) to the top of my for loop above dID_str = str(int(LI)).